# AWK print a CR before line number

Tags: awk

I made a command to dynamically display how many files `tar` has processed:

```
tar zcvf some_archive.tar.gz /a/lot/of/files | \
awk 'ORS="\r"{print NR} END{print "\n"}'
```

In this way, I can see a growing number, as `tar` outputs a line for each file processed.

However, the cursor is always under the first digit. I want it to be after the last digit, so I have this:

```
awk 'ORS=""{print "\r"NR} END{print "\n"}'
```

Sadly, AWK stopped generating any output dynamically.

So how should I do it?

Comment: ITYM `BEGIN{ORS="whatever"}`. As written your script will set ORS for every input line and then only execute the associated action of the result is non-zero and non-null so your 2nd script, for example, will only ever output a single newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why, but changing to printf works for me (and then also you don't need to set ORS):

```
for i in {1..20}; do echo x; sleep 1; done | awk '{printf "\r" NR} END {print ""}'
```

This may be a more satisfying answer, adding a flush to force the output:

```
 for i in {1..20}; do echo x; sleep 1; done | awk -v ORS="" '{print "\r" NR; fflush()} END {print "\n"}'
```

Comment: The OPs 2nd script won't output anything (see my comment under it) and (beyond the missing `BEGIN{}`) the reason why yours works but the OPs first one doesn't is the `\r` returns the cursor to the start of the line so when `ORS="\r"` like the OP had it the cursor returns to the start instantly AFTER every print of NR so it looks like it never leaves that position, while with yours the cursor returns to the start of the line BEFORE the print of NR so it stays there until the next input line is processed.

Comment: Thanks, as always, @EdMorton, what I'm still shaky about is why my printf version does not require a flush, while the print version does. I'm not surprised that the print version requires a flush, because often it takes a newline to push the contents of the buffer to stdout, but with printf I seem to need neither a newline nor a flush.

Comment: print IS affected by the value of ORS so I suspect what you're seeing is an optimization to not do I/O from print when ORS is null until if/when a newline is present, whereas printf is always unaffected by the value of ORS and it's assumed you want full control when you're using it.